# How to align ListView items to bottom of screen when list has few items?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I'd like to have a Xamarin.Forms ListView that starts showing its elements from the bottom up, so that elements are displayed at the bottom of the ListView when there are few items. See the image for explanation. Is this possible to do without having to set the HeightRequest of the ListView manually? (And if setting the HeightRequest manually is required, how can I compute the height of the ListView's child elements when I'm using `HasUnevenRows=true`?)

Here's how I want it to look (few items to the left, many items to the right);

[image: Desired behavior for few items to the left; many items to the right.]

For reference, here is the way ListView normally works when there are few items:

[image: Current behavior for few items.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ListView` is not mandatory, and you just need a repeatable control with templating support - you can use [`ItemsControl`](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Controls/ItemsControl.cs). As it uses `StackLayout` as its panel, it only expands to its required height. So, you don't need to compute it's height. **Please do note `ItemsControl` has very basic virtualization behavior (recycling) - so if you have a lot of items then you will have to modify the control to support virtualization too.**

Secondly, you can extend `Grid` to automatically set the second `RowDefinition` to `Auto` or `Star` as per bottom content size. i.e. by default keep it as `Auto`, but if the content size is greater than 50% of viewport height - then reset `RowDefinition` to `Star`. For eg, you can create a custom `SplitterGrid` as:

```
public class SplitterGrid : Grid
{
    public SplitterGrid()
    {
        RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection() 
        { 
            new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Star }, 
            new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
        };
    }

    void Content2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Height == 0 && Width == 0)
            return;

        Content2.SizeChanged -= Content2_SizeChanged;
        if (Content2.Height > Height / 2)
            RowDefinitions[1].Height = GridLength.Star;
        else
            RowDefinitions[1].Height = GridLength.Auto;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Content1Property =
        BindableProperty.Create(
        "Content1", typeof(View), typeof(SplitterGrid),
        defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: OnContent1Changed);

    public View Content1
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(Content1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Content1Property, value); }
    }

    private static void OnContent1Changed(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((SplitterGrid)bindable).OnContent1ChangedImpl((View)oldValue, (View)newValue);
    }

    void OnContent1ChangedImpl(View oldValue, View newValue)
    {
        if (oldValue == null)
            Children.Add(Content1);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Content2Property =
        BindableProperty.Create(
        "Content2", typeof(View), typeof(SplitterGrid),
        defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: OnContent2Changed);

    public View Content2
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(Content2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Content2Property, value); }
    }

    private static void OnContent2Changed(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((SplitterGrid)bindable).OnContent2ChangedImpl((View)oldValue, (View)newValue);
    }

    void OnContent2ChangedImpl(View oldValue, View newValue)
    {
        if (oldValue == null)
        {
            Children.Add(Content2);
            Content2.SizeChanged += Content2_SizeChanged;
            Grid.SetRow(Content2, 1);
        }
        else 
            Content2.SizeChanged -= Content2_SizeChanged;
    }
}
```

And, usage would look like:

```
<local:SplitterGrid Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <local:SplitterGrid.Content1>
        <ContentView Padding="10" BackgroundColor="#E4E4E4">
            <Label Text="This page contains about 3 items." />
        </ContentView>
    </local:SplitterGrid.Content1>
    <local:SplitterGrid.Content2>
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="End">
            <local:ItemsControl>
                <local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <local:ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </local:ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            </local:ItemsControl>
        </ScrollView>
    </local:SplitterGrid.Content2>
</local:SplitterGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the ItemsControl worked admirably (save for a [recycling bug](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/pull/7)).

Comment: I believe, that should be easy to fix; by adding a clear method in ItemsSource change listener (if new collection count is less than before)

Comment: Yes, I linked to a PR which fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a grid where two rows are defined with one set to "*" or the Height you want in pixels and the bottom one to "Auto" with the listview VerticalOptions set to "End".

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It seems the ListView's expansion in the `Auto` row takes precedence over the expansion of the `*` row. The result was pretty much the same as where I started.